# javascript: chrome extension's content_scripts message event not triggering

Tags: javascript

My extension's content.js:

```
window.addEventListener("message", (e) => {
    console.log("messageEvent");
}, false);
console.log("content.js");
```

Thymeleaf HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test postMessage event</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
        <script Language="JavaScript">
            var testData = {"a":"b"};
            window.parent.postMessage(testData, "*");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The javascript `console.log("content.js");` is showing whenever the page is loaded but when the `window.parent.postMessage(testData, "*");` is executed, the message event from content.js doesn't trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Chrome's Docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/#external-webpage)

First, you should give your extension permission to message in your manifest:

```
"externally_connectable": {
  "matches": ["https://*.yoursite.com/*"]
}
```

I can't see why you used `window.parent.postMessage`.
Use `window.postMessage` instead.

When you listen to request, use the following:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (sender.url === blocklistedWebsite)
      return;  // don't allow this web page access
    if (request.openUrlInEditor)
      openUrl(request.openUrlInEditor);
});
```

Other than that, your code should work.

Comment: @BrianAntiqueña You should use chrome's API to send the message as well.
I just edited my answer.

Comment: do I need to put the below code to my html? I am getting `Cannot read property 'query' of undefined` error

Comment: @BrianAntiqueña The message should be sent from `background.js`.

Comment: The message can be sent backwards, from content script to extension. That example is on the docs.

Comment: Didn't work... I want to send message from tab to content script.

Comment: This is supposed to work on popup.js as well. Just keep in mind to send the message after the page loads(via onload). Reload the extension before you load it.

Comment: It worked after adding window.onload event. So content scripts loads after page is loaded. Thanks